# Using FastZip to zip a directory, and only include certain file types ( file filtering)

Tags: c#, fastzip

I wonder whether there is a way to use [fastzip](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/4007/11539.aspx) to zip a directory, but include only certain file types. I am thinking about using something like:

```
    public static void ZipFiles(string DirectoryToZip, string ZipedFile, string fileFilter, string folderFilter) {
        FastZip fz = new FastZip();
        fz.CreateEmptyDirectories = true;
        fz.CreateZip(ZipedFile, DirectoryToZip, true, fileFilter, folderFilter);
    }
```

The only problem is that the `fileFilter` is given in `string`, not in `arrays`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my own problem; it turns out that I just have to provide a regular expression string to filter the types I want.

Here's an example to include only excel file, word file and xml file into the zip.

```
        FastZip fz = new FastZip();
        fz.CreateEmptyDirectories = true;

        fz.CreateZip(zipFile, prjDir, true, ".*\\.(xls|doc|xml)$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you to create your `FastZip` instance and to add more files later?

If you can, you could to use `Directory.GetDirectories()` method to filter your files and just include that you want.

Comment: Sure I can, but that's a hell load of work, and they are just plumbing job.